# Christmas Dinner in Foreign Country

Tags: cultural-awareness, spanish-language

Due to flight mixups I am  stranded in a foreign country for Christmas.

How does one get invited to Christmas Dinner in Foreign Countries, specifically in Spanish Cultures since Christmas is typically a family affair as I understand it.

Comment: I wouldn't bank on it, with it being a family holiday....

Comment: There is this famous German Hans who got himself invited to an American Christmas party, maybe it would work the other way around too :)

Comment: Might you tell us what country, please?

Comment: Well it's not Spain since it's already past 8 pm here ;)

Comment: Is this a general question or are you trying to get invited to an otherwise stranger's family Christmas dinner?

Comment: @Johns-305 I think the question is pretty clear as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting invited to any different family's christmas is probably going to be a challenge, and if possible probably depend a lot on the family in question.

It's probably a lot easier to find some "public" party arranged for those who have less money/family/friends.